# Local connect to vagrant VM while connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, windows-10, vagrant

I have several local vagrant machines running which work fine.

My problem is that I have to use VPN (forticlient) a lot and when connected to the VPN all access to my local vagrant boxes get routed over the VPN which is really slow.

How can I configure routing under Windows 10 so that I can connect locally to vagrant even when VPN is active?

I tried to reconfigure routing using the Windows "route" command but failed to make it work.

```
Vagrant IPs are 172.28.128.*
OS: Windows 10
VPN client: forticlient
```

If any further informationn is required to solve the problem please ask.

Comment: I have the same question, with Cisco

Comment: Same issue, but on macos